# Is it possible to log into a remote LAN user using the ssh client without using his password?

Tags: ssh, root, remote-access, lan

I am on a LAN network having around 50 systems using ubuntu. I know the root user password used by most of the systems. If i know the root user password of a system, is it possible to ssh into that system with this password? If yes how to do that?

Comment: with (as specify in body) or without (as in title) ? If with, simply issue `ssh -l root 192.168.1.1`and provide password. If without, you have to deploy public key and allow root.

Comment: Can you explain me what actually is this IP 192.168.1.1?

Comment: 192.168.1.1 stand for sample IP of your ubuntu hosts.

Comment: But after using this comment it shows me error `Permission denied (publickey,password).`

Comment: have you allow root login on distant hosts as @Uwe Plonus stated ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can log in to a workstation using root over `ssh` if this is not deactivated (via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`). To allow root login you must add `PermitRootLogin yes` to the file. If it is set to `PermitRootLogin no` then a remote login as root is not possible.

I would also suggest to use `PubkeyAuthentication yes` for remote maintenance.